# Javascript: Hide button on a specific date

Tags: javascript, date, button, hide, survey

I am creating a survey and I need the submit button to be hidden on a specific date. In other words, I need the button to be hidden on 10/22/2013 only and for the button to be visible all other days. I have been ripping my hair out figuring out why the code below does not work...am I missing something?...

```
var x=new Date();
x.setFullYear(2013,9,22);
var today = new Date();

if (x=today)
  {
  document.getElementById('NextButton').style.visibility='hidden';  
  }
else if
  {
  document.getElementById('NextButton').style.visibility='visible';
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning instead of validating:

```
var nextBtn = document.getElementById('NextButton'),
    x = new Date(),
    today = new Date();

x.setFullYear(2013,9,22);

if (x === today) {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = 'hidden';  
} else if {
    nextBtn.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Single `=` assigns, whereas `==` or `===` compares equality.

*Side note:*

`===` is preferred (and therefore used above) because it verifies value and type. `==` verifies only value, i.e. `1 == '1'` because the values match despite one being an integer and one being a string, however `1 !== '1'` because while the value matches, the type does not. Just a little extra info.